# Decrease value on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this example, I am trying to increase value of `span` by selecting an `option`, but I want decrease current value if change option.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var span = +$('span').text();
  var val = +$(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-val');
  var nextNumber = Math.abs(span + val);
  $('span').text(nextNumber);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option data-val="15">Item 1</option>
  <option data-val="25">Item 2</option>
  <option data-val="10">Item 3</option>
</select>

<span>150</span>
```

**For example,** you select Item 3, span text going to set 160, right? now want to change this option, select Item 1, it going to set 175, but I want to increase by new value, it should be 165. I want to decrease previously value, just increase by new selected option.

**Another example,** If you select Item 1, span value should be **165**, if Item 2, **175**, If item 3, **160**.

GOAL: *Increase `span` text just by selected option, and remove/decrease previous values.*

This is what I have done so far but have no idea to decrease previous value, any idea. Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to keep the initial value of the span somewhere:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var span = +$('span').attr('data-initial-val');
  var val = +$(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-val');
  var nextNumber = Math.abs(span + val);
  $('span').text(nextNumber);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option data-val="15">Item 1</option>
  <option data-val="25">Item 2</option>
  <option data-val="10">Item 3</option>
</select>

<span data-initial-val="150">150</span>
```

In the case of another input's that change the span text :

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var span = +$('span').attr('data-initial-value');
  var val = +$(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-val');
  var nextNumber = Math.abs(span + val);
  $('span').text(nextNumber);
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  var span = +  $('span').attr('data-initial-value');
  var val = +$(this).val();
  var selecNumber = +$('select').find('option:selected').attr('data-val');
  if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
    var nextNumber = Math.abs(span + val);
    $('span').text(nextNumber + selecNumber);
      $('span').attr('data-initial-value', nextNumber);
  } else {
    var nextNumber = Math.abs(span - val);
     $('span').attr('data-initial-value', nextNumber);
     $('span').text(nextNumber + selecNumber);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option data-val="15">Item 1</option>
<option data-val="25">Item 2</option>
<option data-val="10">Item 3</option>
</select>

<span data-initial-value="150">150</span>


<input type="checkbox" value="22" />
<input type="checkbox" value="25" />
<input type="checkbox" value="5" />
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. **But**: Use `data-initial-val`, not `initial-val`; [more in the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want. +1.

Comment: @T.J Crowder i just changed to data-initial-value, thanks for the remark !

Comment: Your answer good here on my example, but a little bad for my real code, because span text also affecting from another input , so by your code, I should store final span text in `data-initial-val` , right? or ?

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code? to have a clear idea about what you are doing

Comment: @tourtravel: How is it affected by the other input? The fundamental principal above is applicable generally: Keep your starting point, then calculate the new "value" from first principals on each change. (Side note: You don't have to store the initial value in the span; it could be a variable in your code, for instance.)

Comment: @T.J Crowder there's some cases where this logic is not applicable, if we just have 2 select instead of just one it's not gonna work.

Comment: I accept your answer, because It work with my original question. this is just an extra request for help. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u1a87385/) my real code has some checkbox also. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @tour travel i edited the answer to cover the case you put in jsfiddle